# Merge Missing Dates With The Actual Query

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

I am working on a query where a database may have all dates with corresponding data or may not have. Data in the
table are as follows:

```
ID    DATE
1   6/1/2021
1   6/2/2021
1   6/3/2021
1   6/4/2021
1   6/5/2021
1   6/8/2021 
2   6/4/2021
2   6/5/2021
2   6/8/2021
```

**Expected Output**:

```
ID    DATE
1   6/1/2021
1   6/2/2021
1   6/3/2021
1   6/4/2021
1   6/5/2021
1   6/6/2021
1   6/7/2021
1   6/8/2021 
2   6/1/2021
2   6/2/2021
2   6/3/2021
2   6/4/2021
2   6/5/2021
2   6/6/2021
2   6/7/2021
2   6/8/2021
```

So I tried the following query with `LEFT JOIN` that'll return all required date:

```
WITH all_dates AS (SELECT TO_DATE('01-JUN-2021') + ROWNUM - 1 AS d FROM dual CONNECT BY ROWNUM <= ADD_MONTHS(TO_DATE('01-JUN-2021'), 12 ) - TO_DATE('01-JUN-2021'))
SELECT T.ID, T.DATE FROM all_dates LEFT JOIN TABLE_HERE t on T.DATE = all_dates.d WHERE all_dates.d <= '08-JUN-2021' AND T.ID ('1', '2') AND T.DATE >= '01-JUN-2021' AND T.DATE <= '08-JUN-2021' ORDER BY all_dates.d;
```

Unfortunately this only returns data with matching dates, not the missing one (Missing one will be merged with the actual). Is there anything that I require to do to make it work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To me, it looks as the following query; read comments within code:

```
SQL> with
  2  your (id, datum) as
  3    -- your sample data
  4    (select 1, date '2021-06-01' from dual union all
  5     select 1, date '2021-06-02' from dual union all
  6     select 1, date '2021-06-08' from dual union all
  7     --
  8     select 2, date '2021-06-08' from dual union all
  9     select 2, date '2021-06-04' from dual union all
 10     select 2, date '2021-06-08' from dual
 11    ),
 12  calendar as
 13    -- you already know how to create a calendar; I'm using only 10 days for simplicity
 14    (select date '2021-06-01' + level - 1 datum
 15     from dual
 16     connect by level <= 10
 17    ),
 18  ids (id) as
 19    -- distinct ID values from your sample table (returns two rows; "1" and "2")
 20    (select distinct id from your)
 21  -- final query: cross join of calendar and distinct ID values
 22  select c.datum, i.id
 23  from calendar c cross join ids i
 24  order by i.id, c.datum;
```

The result is

```
DATUM            ID
-------- ----------
01.06.21          1
02.06.21          1
03.06.21          1
04.06.21          1
05.06.21          1
06.06.21          1
07.06.21          1
08.06.21          1
09.06.21          1
10.06.21          1
01.06.21          2
02.06.21          2
03.06.21          2
04.06.21          2
05.06.21          2
06.06.21          2
07.06.21          2
08.06.21          2
09.06.21          2
10.06.21          2

20 rows selected.

SQL>
```